# Dangling pointer in dynamically allocated array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, allocation

Is this a dangling pointer?

```
int x = 25;
int** arr = new int*[5];
*arr[1] = x;
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work... *arr[1] is just a pointer, and is pointing to a valid memory address.

Comment: Where does arr[1] get assigned (i.e. it's currently uninitialized with your code)?

Comment: @H2CO3: It's just a small amount of UB. As far as UB/post goes, this is one of the milder cases!

Comment: @KerrekSB My favorite today was the violation of the `restrict` keyword - OP was sprintffing a buffer onto itself. What a shame (and I even didn't get any upvotes for pointing that out).

Comment: BTW,  a dangling pointer is a pointer to memory that has been freed, but has not been set back to NULL.  Therefore, if you accidently access that pointer thinking that it's still "good", "bad" things will happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arr[1]` is an `int*`, and it's uninitialized. It's undefined behaviour to dereference it.

You could say `arr[1] = &x;`, then `arr[1]` would point to `x` and `*arr[1]` would be 25.

---

Don't forget `delete [] arr;` when you're done.

Comment: Twas a syntax issue then...For some reason, I was thinking that line was dereferencing the int** itself and not the one in the specified location. Thanks Kerreck!